# c# generar formulario de diseño: form1.designer.cs, con CodeDom o Roslyn

Tags: windows-forms

Para realizar un formulario se puede:

```
utilizar el diseñador de visual studio,
hacerlo programaticamente
```

yo estoy haciendo ABMF (Alta, Baja, Modificacion, Ficha (CRUD)) de tablas, programaticamente.

He creado una clase donde defino las tablas y sus propiedades, luego con dicha información diseño el formulario, aún tengo pendiente programar para que dicho formulario sea responsivo al usuario.

Para todas las tablas que utilizo en mis programas creo una clase donde las defino y las creo y como con dicha informacion creo los formularios ABMF (CRUD) me seria muy util poder generar los designer y utilizarlos posteriormente en los programas.

Quisiera que cuando estoy visualizando estos formularios (o cualquier otro) y estoy ejecutando el programa, grabar el form1.designer.cs que corresponde al formulario que estoy visualizando.

No quiero modificar el código fuente de mi programa, lo que quiero es generar codigo para nuevos programas.

El formulario que estoy visualizando fue generado por programación, pero aun no he terminado de desarrollarlo (que funcione total y correctamente).

Entonces momentaneamente quisiera poder generar el Form1.designer.cs para utilizarlo mientras termino de desarrollar las funcionalidades automaticas.

He investigado y encontré como guardar el formulario en visual studio, pero no como hacerlo desde el mismo programa mientras se esta ejecutando.

En cuanto a que he intentado, he googleado y todo lo que he encontrado es como guardar el formulario luego de diseñarlo o guardar una solución.

Tambien he consultado IA pero como siempre sus respuestas son erroneas y pide disculpas y ofrece otras posibles respuestas.

No he encontrado como guardar el diseño del form mientras se ejecuta el programa.

Una forma seria generar linea a linea el form1.designer.cs, pero si visual studio lo genera y lo guarda, deberia existir una forma de hacerlo automaticamente.

Parece que la solucion seria experimentar con las API CodeDom o Roslyn para generar código dinamico.

Talvez alguien con mas conocimiento en estas API pueda ayudarme o guiarme.

La IA chatgpt 4 produjo codigo pero todo lo que genero no genera ni parecido a un form1.designer.cs

```
// Crear un nuevo namespace y una nueva clase
        CodeNamespace codeNamespace = new CodeNamespace("GeneratedForms");
        CodeTypeDeclaration codeClass = new CodeTypeDeclaration("GeneratedForm");
        codeClass.IsClass = true;
        codeNamespace.Types.Add(codeClass);

        // Definir el constructor de la clase
        CodeConstructor constructor = new CodeConstructor();
        constructor.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public;
        codeClass.Members.Add(constructor);

        // Crear un objeto proveedor de código
        CodeDomProvider provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");

        // Configurar opciones de generación de código
        CodeGeneratorOptions options = new CodeGeneratorOptions();
        options.BracingStyle = "C";

        // Generar el código C#
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("GeneratedForm.Designer.cs"))
        {
            provider.GenerateCodeFromNamespace(codeNamespace, writer, options);
        }
```

o

```
            CodeCompileUnit compileUnit = new CodeCompileUnit();
        CodeNamespace ns = new CodeNamespace("DynamicForms");
        compileUnit.Namespaces.Add(ns);

        CodeTypeDeclaration classType = new CodeTypeDeclaration(this.GetType().Name);
        classType.IsClass = true;
        ns.Types.Add(classType);

        // Agregar controles como campos privados
        foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
        {
            CodeMemberField field = new CodeMemberField(control.GetType(), control.Name);
            field.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Private;
            classType.Members.Add(field);
        }

        // Generar código C# en un archivo
        string fileName = this.GetType().Name + ".Designer.cs";
        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName))
        {
            CodeDomProvider provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
            provider.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit(compileUnit, writer, new CodeGeneratorOptions());
        }
```

o

```
            // Crear una unidad de compilación
        CodeCompileUnit compileUnit = new CodeCompileUnit();

        // Crear un espacio de nombres
        CodeNamespace ns = new CodeNamespace("DynamicForms");
        compileUnit.Namespaces.Add(ns);

        // Crear una clase
        CodeTypeDeclaration classType = new CodeTypeDeclaration(this.GetType().Name);
        classType.IsClass = true;
        ns.Types.Add(classType);

        // Generar campos para los controles
        foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
        {
            // Solo se consideran controles del formulario directamente, no subcontroles anidados
            CodeMemberField field = new CodeMemberField(control.GetType(), control.Name);
            field.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Private;
            classType.Members.Add(field);
        }

        // Generar código C# en un archivo
        string fileName = this.GetType().Name + ".Designer.cs";
        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName))
        {
            CodeDomProvider provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
            provider.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit(compileUnit, writer, new CodeGeneratorOptions());
        }
```

o

```
 CodeCompileUnit compileUnit = new CodeCompileUnit();
        CodeNamespace ns = new CodeNamespace("DynamicForms");
        compileUnit.Namespaces.Add(ns);

        CodeTypeDeclaration classType = new CodeTypeDeclaration(this.GetType().Name);
        classType.IsClass = true;
        ns.Types.Add(classType);

        foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
        {
            CodeMemberField field = new CodeMemberField(control.GetType(), control.Name);
            field.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Private;
            classType.Members.Add(field);
        }

        string fileName = this.GetType().Name + ".Designer.cs";
        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName))
        {
            CodeDomProvider provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
            provider.GenerateCodeFromCompileUnit(compileUnit, writer, new CodeGeneratorOptions());
        }


        MessageBox.Show("Archivo Designer.cs generado correctamente.");
```

ninguno de estos codigos genera algo parecido a un form1.designer.cs
he investigado videos sobre codedom, espero alguna guia de alguien que este familiarizado con CodeDom o Roslyn